# How to make toggle buttons handle key pressing simultaneously and independently of each other?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have to create a list of toggle buttons and they've got to react to pressing keystroke `Alt + NUMBER_OF_BUTTON` independently of each other.

Code of this button looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    property bool opened: false
    property int number: 0

    width: 40
    height: 20
    color: (opened) ? "orange" : "grey"
    border.width: 1
    focus: true

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Кл. " + number
        font.pixelSize: parent.width * 0.3
    }

    Keys.onPressed: {
        if (number <= 9 && number >= 0 &&
            event.key == (Qt.Key_0 + number) && (event.modifiers & Qt.AltModifier))
        {
            opened = (opened) ? false : true;
            event.accepted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

However when I try to use these buttons, only the first button in a column reacts to its keystroke.

```
Column {
    Button {
        focus: true
        number: 1
    }
    Button {
        focus: true
        number: 2
    }
    ....
}
```

Could you please explain me what's wrong with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QML several items with active focus / keyboard shortcut control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222257/qml-several-items-with-active-focus-keyboard-shortcut-control)

Comment: The problem is caused by the focus